# Can I install ubuntu-server package in Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: server, .desktop

I know that the LAMP package can be installed on a Ubuntu desktop. But, I am thinking of installing `ubuntu-server` package much like installing `ubuntu-desktop`. So, I ran this command `sudo apt install ubuntu-server`. Will it cause any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't case any problem. You can use it without any issues.

Comment: Thanks. Till now I didn't find any issues. But, is it recommended to have both `ubuntu-server` and `ubuntu-desktop` in one PC? Why or why not?

Comment: As far as I know ```ubuntu-server``` will only install some additional packages over the normally lightweight  ```ubuntu-desktop```. 

I've seen cases where clients install ```ubuntu-desktop``` to get the GUI on  ```ubuntu-server``` machines. Hence there are no problems keeping both ```ubuntu-server``` and ```ubuntu-desktop``` in one PC.